# How to get cell references in a Google Sheets Conditional Formatting custom formula to update (be relative) when pasting the format to other cells

Tags: google-sheets

I have a cell in a google sheet that has a conditional formatting rule containing a custom formula that references another cell (say =isblank(A1)) - this works fine.
When I copy and paste the conditional formatting to another cell the cell reference in the custom formula acts as an absolute reference (that is: it stays as =isblank(A1)) rather than updating as a relative reference should.

I tried a couple of different custom formulae but got the same result.
I would expect references to update when pasted (acting as a relative reference) unless marked as absolute with the usual "$" symbol.
I presume this is a bug, but is there a work around?

Answer (score 0):

Let's test your example.
In `B1` is conditional formatting rule `=ISBLANK(A1)`:

[image]

Now we copy `B1` cell and *Paste special* -> *Conditional formatting only* in `C3`:

[image]

Formula stays same, but range is updated (see red circle above). Since reference to cell in formula is relative it will act as relative. When value is added to `A1` making it non-blank cell, formatting rule will not be met, but in `C3` it still will:

[image]

Until you fill `B3`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I had (reasonably, I think) believed that because the references in the formula hadn't changed when copy'n'paste'd their function hadn't changed to work with the new cells ... but they had. It seems a slightly confusing way of working, but it works. 
Thanks for lightening my darkness.